# java regex pattern to format number with space

Tags: java, regex

I have number

```
1110000010
```

that's need to be formatted so that there is a space inserted after the first 3 characters and another space inserted after another 3 characters so that it looks like:

```
111 000 0010
```

What's the simple java regex pattern to achieve this?

Comment: what's your expected output if the input is, `111000001000` ?

Comment: @Todd No parsing is required, though the given string is always numbers by nature but only thing I care is to insert a space after first 3 and a space after another 3

Comment: @AvinashRaj 111000001000 => 111 000 001000

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it's only 2 spaces you need, capture the 2 groups and write them back out with spaces:

```
str = str.replaceFirst("(...)(...)", "$1 $2 ");
```

Comment: @AvinashRaj When I read the question, I think that is exactly, what OP wants. If he needs something else, it would be good to give more examples and/or a better specification...

Comment: don't know, so i asked it to the op.

Comment: It looks like prefect case for `replaceFirst` instead of `replaceAll`. Not that it will improve performance but readability of code :)

Answer (score 2):

Use capturing groups and a positive lookahead assertion like below.

```
String s = "1110000010";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("(\\d{3})(?=\\d{3})","$1 "));
```

The above regex would capture the three digits only if it's followed by  three digits.

Output:

```
111 000 0010
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/rJ9aU8/5)

OR

```
String s = "1110000010000";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("(?<=^(?:\\d{3}|\\d{6}))"," "));
```

Comment: I actually don't think this is what OP wants. If input was "1110001110000" I think OP wants "111 000 1110000" not "111 000 111 0000". Text from OP: *a space inserted after the first 3 characters and another space inserted after another 3 characters* doesn't mention or imply conditional formatting

Comment: @Bohemian no, i think it's not op wants . OP wants all the three digits which is follwed by a three digits would be seperated by spaces.

Comment: I think OP should specificy more clearly. Everything else is just guessing. ;)

Comment: @brimborium what if the op means for that particular example only?

Comment: @brimborium I think it's clear already. I think this answer overbaked it

Comment: @Bohemian As long as OP does not specify more clearly, both of the answers are correct, but yours does it in a simpler way, thats why I +1ed your answer. ;)